# Find the smallest and second smallest number in an array of 8 numbers with only 9 comparisons

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

This is an interview question I had to answer. Well a friends actually but he asked me and I didnt know the answer also. Hence I'm asking here:

**Given an array of 8 integers, find the smallest and the second smallest integer using only 9 comparisons. More specifically in `n+log(n)-2` time.**

I'm note sure how you can do it using only 9 comparisons. This is how close I have come to it. (10 comparisons)

```
public class Comp {
    static int[] nums = new int[]{9, 4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 6, 1};
    static int compcount = 0;

    //int[] is nums[] array
    public static int[] twoLeast(int[] a){
        int min1 = a[0]; //Prospective lowest number
        int min2 = a[1]; //Prospective second lowest number

        if(isLessThan(min2, min1)){
            min1 = a[1];
            min2 = a[0];
        }

        for(int i=2; i<a.length;i++){
            if(isLessThan(a[i], min1)){
                min2 = min1;
                min1 = a[i];
            }else if(isLessThan(a[i], min2)){
                min2 = a[i];
            }
        }

        return new int[]{min1, min2};
    }

    public static boolean isLessThan(int num1, int num2){
        compcount++;
        return num1 < num2;
    }
}
```

Here I have a function `isLessThan()` to keep track of the number of comparisons.
Again, this does 10 comparisons. How is it possible to do it in 9 comparisons. Or in `n+log(n)-2` time?

P.S: I implemented it in java but it can be any language

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A way to think about the solution is this is like a tennis knock-off competition series. Suppose each number corresponds to a player. Pair off the numbers and let each game correspond to a comparison between numbers within a pair:

Games: `(a1,a2)`, `(a3, a4)`, `(a5, a6)`, `(a7, a8)`

Winners: `a12`, `a34`, `a56`, `a78`

Games: `(a12, a34)`, `(a56, a78)`

Winners: `a1234`, `a5678`

Game: `(a1234, a5678)`

Winner: `a12345678`

Number of games = `7`  ==> `(n - 1)`

The second best will have been defeated only by the winner. Suppose `a3` is the winner. Then the second best will be `a4`, `a12` or `a5678`.

Games: `(a4, a12)`

Winner: `a412`

Games: `a(412, 5678)`

Winner: `a4125678`

So we have `2` games for the second-best ==> `(lg(n) - 1)`

Hence number of games = `7 + 2 = 9` = `(n + lg(n) - 2)`

This is easier to visualize the above competition a tree:

```
               a12345678
              /         \
             /           \
            /             \
           /               \
        a1234            a5678
       /     \           /    \
      /       \         /      \
   a12       a34      a56      a78
  /   \     /   \    /   \    /  \
a1     a2  a3   a4 a5    a6  a7   a8
```

If `a3` is the winner, we have:

```
                   a3
                   |
              /----|----\
             /           \
            /             \
           /               \
          a3 >==========> a5678
       /     \           /    \
      /       \         /      \
   a12 <====< a3      a56      a78
  /   \     /   \    /   \    /  \
a1     a2  a3 ->a4 a5    a6  a7   a8
```

Basically the ultimate winner `a3` will have traversed a path from the leaf to the root (`lg(n) -1`). In his path, he will have defeated the second-best player, which is one of `{a4, a12, a5678}`. So we can just figure out who is the second best by looking at the max in the path apart from the winner which is as described.

Comment: Hi, I like your analogy however the numbers are kinda confusing me in the second part `Then the second best will be a4, a12 or a5678.` How did you get `a4, a12, a5678` Sorry if im asking too much

Comment: It's easier to visualize as a binary tree. The numbers are in the ordered pairs with a number having (3) as the opponent. If (3) is the best, the games it has played are (a3, a4), (a12, a34) and (a1234, a5678). Hence the opponents are a4, a12 and a5678.

Answer (score 6):

As a hint, set up an elimination tournament bracket for the elements of the array to play in. The biggest number in the array will win the tournament, and you'll only need n - 1 comparisons if n is a power of two.

The second-largest element must have lost only to the largest, and in the tournament the largest element only beat log n other elements. Play a second elimination tournament of just those elements to find the largest element there, which requires log n - 1 comparisons.

Overall, only n + log n - 2 total comparisons are needed. All that's left is to code it up.

Hope this helps!